# Array contents would not display

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a javascript code that lets the user input something then it should display after the input but my display seems to not work at all, I am using document.getElementById to display the array content per input but it is not working.

Here is my complete code:

```
<html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <head>
        <title>Sample Array</title>
        <script>var index = 0;</script>
    </head> 

    <body>

        <p id = "display">
        Input:
        <input type="text" id="input">
        <input type="button" value="GO" onClick="press(input.value)">

        <script>

            var sample = new Array();

            function press(Number)
            {               
                    sample[index] = Number;
                    document.getElementById("display").InnerHTML += sample[index] + " ";
                    index++;                    
            }       

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

What seems to be the problem? I am still learning the basics please bear with me.

Comment: Your index variable is undefined/never intialized. Might be better to use sample.push(Number) and get rid of index.

Comment: i declaread index inside the <head> tag as a global variable

Comment: You really shouldn't use global variables

Comment: @Zap7 - i also thought that `press(input.value)` in the onClick looked a little screwy but it does appear to work.  I guess it's time to read a bit deeper about onClick attributes in HTML. ;)

Comment: Try using 
sample[index] =document.getElementbyId("input");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with "InnerHTML". The correct syntax is "innerHTML" with small "i".

Comment: Codes here are really case sensitive. I need to get used to this. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
document.getElementById("display").InnerHTML
```

to

```
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML
```

(note the lowercase **i**

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K4U6a/)

Comment: gonna mark this as the answer as you replied first. Thanks alot. The codes are really case sensitive ><

Answer (score 1):

I made two tiny changes that seem to make this work.

First, close the `<p>` tag so that when you set `innerHtml` it does not include the inputs.

Second, change `InnerHHTML` to `innerHTML`.  Methods and properties are case sensitive.

```
    <p id = "display"></p>
    Input:
    <input type="text" id="input">
    <input type="button" value="GO" onClick="press(input.value)">

    <script>

        var sample = new Array();

        function press(Number)
        {               
                sample[index] = Number;
                document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += sample[index] + " ";
                index++;                    
        }       

    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the </p> closing i did not notice that i left it open.

Answer (score 1):

First your <p> is not complete;
<p id = "display"></p>

Second its:

```
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += sample[index] + " ";
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I will now continue my experiment.